# Mx Notify Control doesn't work when bulk-editing

Tags: mx-notify

My client has been using MX Notify Control for some time to notify authors when their entries have been approved (status switched from *Pending* to *Open*). She tells me that when administrators approve a single entry, it works. But if they select a few entries and set all their statuses to *Open* at once, the notifications are not sent.

Should it work when editing multiple entries at once, or only for one at a time?

Comment: Have you contacted the developer?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the extension does not contain this functionality.

Little side note: When saving an entry the hook "entry_submission_end" is called. For saving multiple entries the hook "update_multi_entries_loop" should be called, wich is not the case.